# Data Manupulation Issue in cognos

Tags: sql, db2, cognos, cognos-8

One column contains the below case statement, when data is rendered the negative decimal value comes up wrong.

correct Value= **-0.9** but it displays as **.-9**
i tried manipulating by changing data format etc. but not getting correct result

I want to manipulate the data somehow and show it as  -0.9

case when
cast([Relational Layer].[Amount],varchar(40)) <> '-2000.00'
then cast([Relational Layer].[Amount],varchar(40))
else 'Not Available'
end

Answer (score 0):

I believe your facing a cast conversion issue.  I see several solutions.  Before you read any further please double check your format settings for the column on the report... it just seems like you have a format applied when you can't really do that since its a text field.

Not In Any Order

1. It looks like you are trying to convert to varchar so you can make use of "Not Available".  You might want to try a different approach.  Change your case expression to do pure math without any varchar casting.  And i'm guessing you may be displaying in report studio so in report studio and using report studio you can setup a conditional variable/style that while displaying the value has a if -2000 or whatever test condition set it to "Not Available"
2. You could create two columns in your query subject ... one has your case statement but only populates when "Not Available" the other is purely numeric and populates only when it is a real value.  In the report you can also use a variable/conditional style in the column to show one column or the other based on testing the Not Available... If Not Available then show not available column otherwise show numeric column.
3. Have a purely numeric case expression that returns the right value.  but in the case expression have it return null instead of "Not Available".   In the report i believe there is a direct way to default a value when null or again you can do a conditional style/variable to do this for you.

Conditional Styles/Variables are real handy for doing crazy substituations/evaluations on the display and they can operate on a row by row basis.

Comment: Thanks Tim for your response. As you mentioned I'm trying to convert to varchar so I can make use of "Not Available", but I have 10 columns like this , the second approach is not feasible, I tried multiplying with 1.0 so it will return in decimal, but its not allowing to multiply also since its varchar.

Comment: I"m certain #1 or #2 will work.  Not sure which version of Cognos your using... but they do have the default property now on column values so it should be very easy to default a numeric column to "Not Available" when it is null... and if it is an older version the Conditional Variables/Styles will work absolutely without a doubt.